# iOS app missing keyboard language selection

Tags: ios, keyboard, language, internationalization

I am having an issue with an iOS application which doesn't allow choosing between configured iOS keyboard languages except for English and Emoji

The very same app (in this case, Bolt) shows the language selection normally on my wife's device.

I've had the issue before with some other apps, but that happens rarely so I don't recall which apps they were. In either case, it doesn't seem a problem with an app, as on other devices the language selection looks fine.

Here is the screenshot from Bolt and Uber, running on the same device.

I have searched the internet but couldn't find other reports of the same issue, probably due to many other topics around the same keywords.

[image: Bolt with English and Emoji only]
[image: Uber with all languages filler]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are saying the keyboard languages show up properly in all Apps except a few. Is this right? Are you connected to the internet when the problem occurs? I ask because some language items (e.g., voice dictation) only work properly when an internet connection is available (sometimes you can't even see the mic, shown in your image). Like you, I have 4 languages installed (although I removed emojis). At times I've experienced problems (though different from yours) and I did something like the following to solve them:

```
1) remove each keyboard language (except native) via settings-->general-->keyboards
2) restarted the device
3) re-added each keyboard language via settings-->general-->keyboards
```

In your case, I suggest you delete the problem App(s) before step (3) and then re-add them after step (3)

If you are able to see the language keyboards in most Apps (Mail, Notes, etc...) but just not in some problem Apps, I would contact the developer, sending them a screenshot.